# Yii2 UrlManager: совпадение только по первому и последнему

Tags: yii2, url

Всем привет. Делаю сайт на Yii2 и стала задача вывода каталога. Каждая категория имеет свой уникальный slug, есть вложенные категории. И вот проблема в том, что я не знаю, какой уровень вложенности. То есть, может быть так `/catalog/kuzov/art-001`, может так `/catalog/kuzov/zerkala/art-002`, а может и так `/catalog/kuzov/zerkala/zadnie/art-003`.

Могу ли я написать в urlManager такое правило, которое будет обрабатывать все эти запросы? Например

```
'catalog/<что-угодно>/art-<id:\d+>' => 'catalog/article'
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 0):

Если нет необходимости выводить каждый уровень вложенности в отдельную переменную, тогда можно просто объединить все в одну переменную в примере как показано ниже.

```
'catalog/<slug:[\w\/]+>/art-<id:\d+>' => 'catalog/article'
```

В $_GET у тебя теперь будет и id и slug, который будет включать в себя все вложенности:

```
catalog/kuzov/art-001                => id: 001, slug: 'kuzov'
catalog/kuzov/zerkala/art-002        => id: 002, slug: 'kuzov/zerkala'
catalog/kuzov/zerkala/zadnie/art-003 => id: 003, slug: 'kuzov/zerkala/zadnie'
```

Дальше этот slug можно будет разбить на массив, или делать с ним что тебе нужно.

Comment: прописал ваше правило, но оно не срабатывает для такого url `catalog/fil-tr/maslyanyy-fil-tr/art-SFUgNzEyLzggeA` (art-<id:\d+> я заменил на art-<article>)

Comment: добавил еще символ "-" в правило slug

Comment: @Diefair советую использовать сайт https://regex101.com/ для тестирования. По сути, тут используются регулярные выражения с небольшой модификацией. Можете написать столько кейсов сколько вам необходимо и проверить, что все работает. К примеру `catalog/<slug:[\w\/]+>/art-<id:\d+>` надо будет упростить до `catalog\/[\w\/]+\/art-\d+`